# ShowBalloonTip Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon, balloon-tip

On Windows 10, the `ShowBalloonTip` method of `NotifyIcon` NEVER shows the balloon tip. This would appear to have something to do with Windows itself.

If I go to `Settings > System > Notifications & actions` > and find my running app (`vshost32.exe` in debug mode) and click on it, then turn on `Show notifications in the action center`, I can clearly see the balloon tip messages being added to the notifications, but never a balloon tip.

I assume this is a problem with Windows 10.

My `NotifyIcon` is `VISIBLE`

```
my_icon.ShowBalloonTip("Title", "Message", BalloonIcon.Info);
```

Answer (score 13):

On my computer with Windows 10 version 1803, go to Settings > System > Notifications & actions, and turn on "Get notifications from apps and other senders". 
The ballontips from my WPF app will show up.

Answer (score 8):

Found the problem - was simple: Quiet Hours was turned on in the notification center and this was preventing the balloon tips.

Comment: Also note that, on Windows 10, the Push Notifications service must be running (wasn't your case but may help someone else). I had disabled it because I thought it was related to remote notifications (coming from remote servers), but it turned out it also handles the notifications from local apps, both toasts and balloons.

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed the problem by adding **icon** property. If this property isn't set, the baloontip won`t be shown. Here's example of my code:

```
var notify = new NotifyIcon();
notify.Visible = true;
notify.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"D:\Users\User\Desktop\some.ico");
int code = new Random().Next(1000, 9999);
notify.ShowBalloonTip(500, "code", $"{code}", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn off Focus Assist. If you are using second screen, turn off "When I'm duplicating my display" option. My settings is like that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me/

Answer (score 2):

Change the Solution Configuration "Debug mode to Release mode" with X64 or X32 Solution platform. It will start work.

```
 public static NotifyIcon trayIcon;
 trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
 trayIcon.Icon = new Icon("Images/Test.ico");
 trayIcon.Visible = true; trayIcon.Text=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
 ContextMenu contextMenu1 = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Menu2", Menu2_Event);
contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Menu3", Menu3_event);
contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Exit", Close_Click);
trayIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
trayIcon.BalloonTipText = "Hi Test";
trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these solved my issue :(

But by accident I fixed it! My problem was I had my project configured for 32-bit on a 64-bit platform and for whatever reason they only show up when when I run the project for Any CPU (64-bit in this case)!!

Hopefully that helps some of you, it was a real mystery for me...

(I also posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003509/105028) because these are duplicate questions)

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, as @rmirabelle wrote in the question "My NotifyIcon is VISIBLE". This is actually important.
If the notification icon is not visible in the systray, the `BalloonTips` won't show up either.

Possible sources for invisibility are:

- Visible property = false
- No icon is set for the `NotifyIcon` object