# C# NotifyIcon tooltip not showing (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows-10, notifyicon

I'm having trouble getting my `ShowBalloonTip()` to work on Windows 10. My NotifyIcon is set up as following:

[image: Screenshot of NotifyIcon in Visual Studio]

I don't think I'm missing anything there. I try to show my tooltip using `NotificationObj.ShowBalloonTip(1000);` and nothing appears to happen. I've read about issues with UAC etc, so I tried running my program as administrator, didn't help either. I've tried showing the tooltip both while focused on my form, and also while not. Nothing seems to work.

The icon does get added to the system tray just fine, though. Does anyone know what might be my problem?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444541/showballoontip-not-working

Comment: Oh my, how did I not think of that..... You're totally right @AlexK. I had my notifications set to "Priority only" thanks!